# <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> Meaning

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I wanted to know what is the meaning of

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

I am using IIS 7.5 and I have a simple web application. Do I need to write this in my web.config file.
I have also written few http handler for jquery ajax call.
I am using form authentication and asp.net 4.0.

How can I determine which module I have to run and which is not to be?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

**Modules Preconditions:**

> The IIS core engine uses preconditions to determine when to enable a particular module. Performance reasons, for example, might determine that you only want to execute managed modules for requests that also go to a managed handler. The precondition in the following example (`precondition="managedHandler"`) only enables the forms authentication module for requests that are also handled by a managed handler, such as requests to .aspx or .asmx files:
>
> ```
> <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
> ```
>
> If you remove the attribute `precondition="managedHandler"`, Forms Authentication also applies to content that is not served by managed handlers, such as .html, .jpg, .doc, but also for classic ASP (.asp) or PHP (.php) extensions. See "[How to Take Advantage of IIS Integrated Pipeline](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline)" for an example of enabling ASP.NET modules to run for all content.
>
> You can also use a shortcut to enable all managed (ASP.NET) modules to run for all requests in your application, regardless of the "`managedHandler`" precondition.
>
> **To enable all managed modules to run for all requests without configuring each module entry to remove the "`managedHandler`" precondition, use the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` property in the `<modules>` section:**
>
> ```
> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
> ```
>
> When you use this property, the "`managedHandler`" precondition has no effect and all managed modules run for all requests.

Copied from [IIS Modules Overview: Preconditions](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#Precondition)

Comment: is it good to run all the models for all the request or I shall be more specific over there. Does this affect the speed of the application?

Comment: Yes there will be performance issue. You should use precondition instead.

Comment: then how should I decide which module I have to use and which to not.

Comment: A follow-up question. I see it's possible to enable seperate modules as well, in stead of all. See my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998816/dot-character-in-mvc-web-api-2-for-request-such-as-api-people-staff-45287), the solution there was to add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`. But I see now it might create overhead. So, is there a specific module responsible that I can enable to get the dot "." in MVC WebAPI Url, in stead of just enabling them all with `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`? Is it for example the "UrlAuthorization" module?

Comment: adding the modules tag section works for me.  I use MVC 5, .net framework 4.5.0, IIS 7 and windows server 2008

Comment: For whatever reason this doesn't work for me.  IIS Express.

Comment: IIS [Express] shows 404-Not-Found with some ugly html, with that setting on, for requests with dot or plus characters (not url-encoded) as the part of the last url-segment not followed by a slash-character. I do realize that such path resembles a potential file-path, but that makes that setting a lie: such request never makes it to the application.