# How to pass email as a parameter at the end of URL in ASP.NET MVC web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

How to pass email as a parameter at the end of URL in ASP.NET MVC web API?

like below:

```
test.com/api/sales/getcustomerorders/test@test.com
```

I want to pass the email address as a parameter to the getcustomerorders action.

we can pass using query string. But I want to format the url like above.

Thanks.

Comment: you have to encode the @ sign in the URL as it is a reserved character. Should look something like this: test.com/api/sales/getcustomerorders/test%40test.com

Comment: I tried the same url here(with @) and it works.. What's going wrong?

Comment: It's the DOT that is the problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In WebApiConfig make the route as "/{email}/". The end "/" will prevent you from getting   No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI ...

Comment: Easy and simple solution. No configuration changes or anything else needed. Thanks for posting.

Comment: This worked for me. Can you please explain why this works? I don't understand it.

Comment: The reason it works is it takes that field {email} and it will match that vs the string it is expecting for email, which matches anything following that, including a@b.com and stuffs it into the email var.   LOVE this answer btw I spent a few hours trying to google special chars to avoid and everything else (worked until I put an '@' in the URL, then it redirected to login - which was very weird.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that you have period in the url.

In order to make it work, change you web config to add following two configurations:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Haacked has a blog about relexUrlToFileSystemMapping http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

And I have a bug about it in IIS express 8 and need the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/226

Comment: It works but if you refer to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning) it will slow your app because you load all module for all requests..

Comment: just runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests is needed to allow an email address since a period is used in the URL

Answer (score 7):

Scott Hanselman covers this in [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx). As an alternative you could pass the email as a query string parameter and not as part of the path since certain characters are not allowed.