# ASP.NET Web API 5.2.3 Attribute Route returning 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've got an ASP.NET Web API project that I'm working on.  I've got an APIController called SpellbookController  that has basic CRUD operations to an EntityFramework repository.

However, when I try to add a method that takes a parameter that's not an id, I can't seem to get it to route correctly.

Here's what it looks like:

```
// GET: api/Spellbooks/user@email.com
[ResponseType(typeof(List<Spellbook>))]
[Route("api/Spellbooks/{username}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSpellbook(string username)
{
    List<Spellbook> spellbooks = db.Spellbooks.Where(x=>x.Username == username).ToList();
    if (spellbooks == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(spellbooks);
}
```

So I'm trying to hit http://localhost:xxxx/api/Spellbooks/emailaddress,
but I get a 404 every time.

It's definitely an APIController, and I have `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` turned on.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your username parameter?

Your call should looks like this-

```
 http://localhost:xxxx/api/Spellbooks/emailaddress/David
```

**Update**

Try to declare the parameter as string `{username:string}`

**Update 2**

The problem is with your '.' as you can see in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085661/webapi-method-with-email-address-parameter-returns-404-from-httpclient).
You can send the email without the point in the parameter and then replace ite back to you regular mode or you can use all the good advice that the link provide.

Comment: oh sorry, `emailaddress` is the parameter I'm talking about, because their username is their email address.

Comment: So I guess I'm calling it http://localhost:xxxx/api/Spellbooks/test@test.com.

does that help?

Comment: Try to do it with simple string, and see what happen. Maybe there is problem with the email as string.

Comment: That was it!  Is there any way to send an email address as a string?

Comment: @AlexKibler, I just added update, does the first update solve your problem?so  I will delete the update 2 section...

Comment: I actually just decided to use a userId instead of the email, but your second update would work perfectly, according to that link.  I marked this accepted because it was your advice that led me to getting the right answer

Answer (score 0):

If you step through it, do you get a value when looking at `username`? Or is it always null?

If your route is not working, a simple way to debug the route is to make a request to `http://localhost:xxxx/api/Spellbooks/?emailaddress=thisemailaddress` and see if you can get a response. In fact, from a REST standard, it can be argues that it's a cleaner route, since you will be returning a collection of elements, rather than a single object.

Comment: It wasn't capable of being stepped through.  it was ASP.NET that was throwing the 404.  However, I ended up just switching to a UserId instead of a username, and that's working just fine.

Comment: So, basically, it was the route that wasn't getting hit?