# url routing doesn't work for old asp file

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, url-routing

I am using url routing with asp.net web forms.

If Url doesnt exist I am redirecting the user to my custom error page.

It works with aspx page but old asp links (old asp not .net) getting error 404.

For example :

http://www.worldweddingguide.com/companies.asp

http://www.worldweddingguide.com/companies.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. on ASP handler, check the option 'check if file exsits'.
2. set IIS's 404 url (not ASP.net one!) by web.config 'system.webServer' or with IIS GUI.
   www.stokia.com/support/misc/web-config-custom-httperrors.aspx
3. see also: [<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> Meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning)

Comment: I already try.  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>

Comment: and 'check if file exists'?