# Asp.Net MVC route action method doesn't call when there is a DOT (.) at the end of url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

### Configured Route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "RedirectToProduct",
  url: "product/page/p{productId}/{shortName}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "RedirectToProduct", shortName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

### Action Method:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> RedirectToProduct(string productId, string shortName)
    {
    }
}
```

### Problem..

- When I hit url  http://localhost:1234/product/page/p1185/ , then I am
  getting call in controller's action method
- BUT when I hit url http://localhost:1234/product/page/p118.5 , I am
  NOT getting call in controller's action method. I see HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found (See there is DOT (.) in productId.)

What I want is- whether I add DOT (.) in the end OR not in productUd parameter, call should go in the controller's action method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any other routes defined before that one that might be interfering?

Comment: no @DanielJ.G., there are only 2 routes defined. This is the 1st one and then the default one.

Comment: I feel that your question and description conflict.

Comment: Should work without issues. Just tried that and it all works here. You have a test project that simulates the issue?

Comment: Hello @L-Three, Thanks for the efforts.. I just realized that- when I use DOT (.) at the end, it is NOT working... E.g. http://localhost:1234/product/page/p118.5

Comment: Do you mean you have the problem only if you use a dot? Bedause that too should just work. It would be best to provide a sample solution, because it should work.

Comment: Yes @L-Three, when I use DOT in productId, it is NOT calling action method, it shows HTTP 404 error in browser..

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Provide a sample app...

Comment: @L-Three Just try to use this url in your sample app... http://localhost:1234/product/page/p118.5   You will see the issue.. You will NOT get a call in action method.. May be because it treat as an extension...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dot is the problem, like `product/page/p118.5`, then add `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = true` to your web.config, like:

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     ...
   </modules>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks @L-Three ! Do you think there there is any side-effect of having this flat to true??

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning