# MVC MapRoute gets 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

I have created the following MapRoute function. And it's being called right from Application_Start() in Global.asax.

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes( RouteCollection routes )
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "TestMe",
                url: "TestMe.axd",
                defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "SignOn" }
            );
    }
}
```

While I can access the specific controller if I use

```
http://localhost/TestSite/Access/SignOn,
```

I can't access it with this URL.

```
http://localhost/TestSite/TestMe.axd.
```

Can someone please point out what I am missing here?

Many thanks!!

Comment: It is trying to search TestMe.axd file on physical location.. check your IIS mappings to fix it. or else you might need to write HTTPHandler to avoid this error.

Comment: Perhaps you need to remove `.axd` handlers in your `Web.Config`

Comment: I did remove them from <HttpHandlers>, it was the first thing to do. But wasn't working still. 

By the way, the handler look like this:

<add verb="*" path="TestMe.axd" type="TestMe.Core, TestMe.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4faaf89e72cdf57a"/>

Answer (score 1):

Found some information from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning)

I added

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

into my Web.config and it's working now.