# Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I don't know why, but the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute() function running many times - as the number of files in the page. 
(for example: if my web page including 5 jpg, 3 css files and 4 js files, this function will execute 12 times!). It's make me a lot of problems and also slow my site. I prefer that the function will execute only ONE time. does anyone know why it's running a lot of times?
maybe to change something in the routes?

Comment: Probably because `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is true? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning

Comment: Tnx! helps me a lot.