# PutAsync Not Working - web Api2 and MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We have an application running MVC4 front end an consuming a web api2 rest PUT. It is running in IIS 8.5 and windows server 2012

I am using PutAsync to update some data but getting a 405 - Method Not Allowed back. i looked around and found out that some people had this issue and it was resolved by using some or other technique in the web.config of the API.

I tried this in the web API config and it worked for me.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
   <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>

<handlers>
 <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```

BUT I am not sure why. i don't have any webdav authoring rules defined for my web site. Can someone please help me understand why this might be working for me??

Also, is there a downside of setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true for the API??

Answer (score 0):

The configuration can be inhertied from `machine.config`. For more info,[Configuration Inheritance in this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685.aspx). It can also be inherited from any other `web.config` in a containing folder.

`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` implies that any request done to the folder (and subfolders) where you include this `web.config` will be handled to the registered modules. For example it will try to handle the request to something that doesn't look like a Web API action. Please, see this: [<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> Meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning)