# How to configure IIS application to work as a gateway

Tags: asp.net, rest, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have written an ASP.NET Web API which is basically an API gateway. The base URL of the gateway is `http://localhost:88/ApiGateway`. The service I have implemented looks up some header values and cookies in order to route a request. Currently I use it for blue-green deployments.

When a header or cookie with a specific API-ID is found, the request is routed to the corresponding API.

For example, if the found API-ID is `alpha-v1.7.4`, and the URL is `http://localhost:88/gateway/app/login.html`, the request is routed to `http://localhost:8080/app/alpha-v1.7.4/app/login.html` where the actual app or website resides.

This work perfectly when using OWIN and Katana. All URLs are routed correctly.

When installing the gateway in IIS, things are getting strange.

I have put a very verbose logging into the gateway which logs each request and the found route. On IIS I observe that the followings requests are reaching the gateway and are routed properly:

```
1: http://localhost:88/gateway/app/some_directory/
2: http://localhost:88/gateway/app/another_directory_with_a.dot/
3: http://localhost:88/gateway/app/some_path_no_trailing_slash
```

The following request do **not** reach the gateway:

```
4: http://localhost:88/gateway/app/no_trailing_slash_with_a.dot
5: http://localhost:88/gateway/app/index.html
```

To me it seems that IIS is letting pass any *directory* paths (i.e. with a trainling slash like `.../.../directory/`), all *resource* path (i.e. with no trailing slash like `.../.../resource`) which do not smell like a file (since they have not dot), but blocks paths which have no trailing slash but a dot inside (`.../.../may_be_a.file` is blocked, but `.../.../not_a.file/` passes).

Following these instruction did not work for me: [How to disable Request Filtering for a specific website on IIS 7.5?](https://serverfault.com/questions/359635/how-to-disable-request-filtering-for-a-specific-website-on-iis-7-5)

Any idea how to configure IIS to get this to work?

Comment: I don't know how you're doing your redirects. But perhaps you need to [RAMFAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning) it.

Comment: @mason: RAMMFAR does not work for me - don't know why not, but I came around with a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

After messing around with [RAMMFAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048863/modules-runallmanagedmodulesforallrequests-true-meaning) which did not work for me, I came around with this solution:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Just clearing all handlers and adding the one and only I need solved the problem.