# SignalR not working in local IIS Web Server

Tags: silverlight, signalr

We're using SignalR to push notifications to a Silverlight frontend. It works smoothly when running under the ASP.NET development server, but when switching to Local IIS Web Server the messages never come through to the frontend. Have setup a breakpoint on the HubProxy's event handler and never gets called.

BTW I have checked this question - [Signalr/Hub not loading in IIS 7 but working correctly in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053229/signalr-hub-not-loading-in-iis-7-but-working-correctly-in-visual-studio) - and we already have those settings in our web.config file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit: It is working under IIS Express too, but not IIS 7.5

Comment: Did you find/fix the problem you were having?.

Comment: Haven't been given a proper Windows Server to test it out yet. I guess it's normal to have problems with IIS 7.5 on a desktop machine. In the meantime IIS Express is doing the job well.

Comment: Fixed by following these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185322/silverlight-signalr-and-iis-applications-off-of-the-default-web-site

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579598/signalr-mvc-site-loads-indefinitely-after-signalr-install

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, this has a limit of the number of concurrent connections you can have ([max of 10 on Ultimate](http://www.jpelectron.com/sample/WWW%20and%20HTML/IIS-%20OS%20Version%20Limits.htm) ). However on IIS Express, there are no limits. That's the only difference I can think of right now, why it works on Express but not on IIS 7.5.