# SignalR - works on Cassini an IIS Express but not on Windows 2008 with IIS 7.0

Tags: iis, iis-7, signalr

We've got SignalR running on a Silverlight 5 client.
It is working on our local machines under both cassini and IIS Express, but it isn't when we deploy the app to our dev server, which runs Windows 2008 Server and IIS 7.0 
We don't see any errors on the logs, just the notifications not coming through to the client.

Any ideas? We have rerun the aspnet_regiis tool and also added thr web.config settings recommended in another posts with no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you made sure the Application Pool is .NET 4.0 / Integrated pipeline?

Comment: Fixed by following these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185322/silverlight-signalr-and-iis-applications-off-of-the-default-web-site

Comment: What other config recommendations did you follow. I'm having difficulty getting Owin to start.