# signalR MVC site loads indefinitely after signalR install

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I created a brand new MVC4 app. Installed new signalR package from NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR –pre
```

Whenever I run it, it loads indefinitely. I know it is caused by SignalR => App_Start/RegisterHubs that was added during install because it never gets passed "`RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` " line when in debug.

tried it on several machines running windows 7 and Vs2012 and IIS Express

what gives??

thanks

```
UPDATE:
```

I just tried it on my home computer. Created a brand new MVC4 app, ran nuget package install and **IT WORKS FINE! :)** (same set up vs2012, win7, IIS express).

This is weird because everything AT MY OFFICE worked just fine until i installed the new version of signalR.

- could it be that at work we're *behind a proxy*?
- -why would that make a difference?
- -how can I check if all the files are installed correctly during nuget install at work? What should should i be looking for/check?

one more thing: When I had **previous/older** version of signalR installed (without the RegisterHubs file) everything worked fine.

thanks

Comment: I have dramatically slower load time with SignalR installed on MVC4, at the same point as you, but it does eventually load. I assumed this was just an issue related to this being alpha code, and not ready for production.

Comment: I let it load for more than 10 min...still no go.

Comment: I have the Service Bus backplane installed as well (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Azure-service-bus), and I wasn't sure if that was making it slower. Hopefully these alpha issues will get worked out before release.

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure this has nothing to do with the MapHubs call. If that were the case, this would be the most commonly reported issue and no signalr sites would every work ever. So I'm guessing it has something to do with your environment.

Comment: please see update on this issue. thanks

Comment: When you create a brand new project does it work at work? I'm not sure how being behind a proxy would hang the MapHubs call. Run fiddler and see if it makes any difference or see if you can see any errors.

Comment: A poor moderating decision from casperOne IMO - this is a live question with plenty of relevance. @dfowler - I've confirmed that MapHubs significantly slows my MVC4 app on the Azure emulator, running on IIS Express, but I'll post a separate question now this is closed.

Comment: Where did the Azure Emulator come into the picture? You mentioned your work proxy. Like I said it's something environmental and we have yet to narrow it down.

Comment: @dfowler (That was the OP referring to his work proxy) I'm sure you're right - it's either the environment or an issue with my code. I've posted a detailed question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612970/signalr-seems-to-be-slowing-startup-of-my-mvc-azure-application  It's not only in the emulator, but on live Azure also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And,  For indefinite load times when running the site on IIS Express, Please check your IIS from ControlPanel-->Programs and Features-->Turn windows features on or off-->Internet Information Service. Check whether all the relevant features are assigned in World wide Web services under IIS., I came across with Same issue., I activated relevant features., Now, No indefinite loading.., :) Hope it will helpful for you or someone.

thanks,
Shanthini.

Comment: could you please try to improve a bit on your spelling? Remember: in English, most words start with a lowercase letter :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

Changing from IIS Express to VS Development Server OR Local IIS helped. Now everything works fine. Not sure what caused indefinite load times when running the site on IIS Express with Proxy at work.

thanks