# SignalR seems to be slowing startup of my MVC / Azure application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, azure, signalr

I have an MVC application running under .NET 4.5 on a WebRole on Windows Azure, employing SignalR 1.0 -alpha2, and using the ServiceBus backplane. In my App_Start folder I have RegisterHubs.cs, as follows:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(pageengine.studio.RegisterHubs), "Start")]

namespace pageengine.studio
{
    public static class RegisterHubs
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        }
    }
}
```

And in Global.asax, I have the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    String connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://MYNAMESPACE.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=MY_ISSUER;SharedSecretValue=MY_SECRET_VALUE";
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseWindowsAzureServiceBus(connectionString, 1);
}
```

I've run tests as above (call this MVC + SignalR + ServiceBus), with the `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver ...` line in Global.asax commented out (MVC + SignalR), and with both lines `[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod ...` and `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` also commented out (MVC Alone).

Before beginning, I fire up the Azure emulator using Start Without Debugging (and deploying to IIS Express), and after each commenting / uncommenting, I rebuild the application, then do a hard reload in Google Chrome. My average load times over ten tests are as follows:

> MVC Alone: 1.33 seconds
>
> MVC + SignalR: 31.95 seconds
>
> MVC + SignalR + ServiceBus: 53.1 seconds

I have not run the same comparison on my live Azure site, but the reason for running these tests is that after implementing SignalR, it is running noticeably slower.

I had assumed this was just due to SignalR being in alpha, but discussion elsewhere ([signalR MVC site loads indefinitely after signalR install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13579598/signalr-mvc-site-loads-indefinitely-after-signalr-install)) suggests this shouldn't be so. I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my implementation above, or if this is an Azure-specific issue, or something else.

Is anybody else experiencing similar performance issues? Is there anything wrong with my code above? Does anyone have any potential remedies?

**Update**

I've added a trace statement to the WebRole Start and Run methods, to the beginning and end of the `RegisterHubs` method, and to the beginning and end of the `Application_Start` method, and commented out the ServiceBus code so I'm just testing MVC + SignalR.

Again, over a number of tests, the results are consistent:

> Web Role OnStart: 20:55:17
>
> Web Role Run: 20:55:17
>
> RegisterHubs Start In: 20:55:28
>
> RegisterHubs Start Out: 20:56:10 // 42 seconds. Average was nearer 45.
>
> Application_Start In: 20:56:14
>
> Application_Start Out: 20:56:21

For reference, my RegisterHubs method now looks like this:

```
public static void Start()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterHubs Start In: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RegisterHubs Start Out: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
```

**Further Update**

The issue is (ironically enough) in the `PerformaceCounterManager` class, in the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core` assembly.

The function `SetCounterProperties()` calls `LoadCounter` over a loop of 23 different `_counterProperties`. Each of these calls fails and the exception is handled, resulting in a return of `_noOpCounter`, but the fail is taking between one and two seconds to occur, and this accumulates to a forty second lag (all these timings with the debugger on - it's quicker without, of course, but still perceptibly laggy).

Here's a trace of the handled exception, in case that's useful:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll
InvalidOperation: SignalR - Errors: Hub Invocation Total - deployment18(966).Azure.Studio_IN_0_Web - System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot load Counter Name data because an invalid index '' was read from the registry.
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.GetStringTable(Boolean isHelp)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_NameTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.get_CategoryTable()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.CategoryExists(String machine, String category)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName, String machineName)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(String categoryName)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.PerformanceCounterManager.LoadCounter(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName) in d:\Work\CLIENTS\PageEngine\Resources\SignalR-master\src\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core\Infrastructure\PerformanceCounterManager.cs:line 275`

Easiest workaround I could find was to have no PerformanceCounters. <strike>For the time being I've modified `GetPropertyInfo()` to return simply `new PropertyInfo[0]`.</strike> I've modified `LoadCounter` to always return `_noOpCounter`. Startup time is now about 5 seconds, or 10 with the Service Bus.

Comment: The second one makes no sense. MVC + SignalR + azure with a single role without service bus shouldn't slow down anything.

Startup with service bus turned on makes sense as it has to create topics and subscriptions.

Comment: @dfowler Yes, I'm not surprised at the ServiceBus time, but the other results are absolutely consistent. I'll try to put some tracings on the various calls and see if I can identify the bottleneck.

Comment: @dfowler Updated - see above. The time is definitely being lost in the MapHubs() call. Not sure why. What can I do to investigate further? Finishing for tonight but will look at this again tomorrow (UK time).

Comment: Get the source and start debugging :). You can ping me in jabbr for more details.

Comment: @dfowler - see update above. Issue is with `LoadCounter` in `PerformaceCounterManager`.

Comment: Can you file a bug on github with these details. I think we can just skip this phase if one fails to initialize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in SignalR 1-alpha2, now reported on github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1063

**Update**

... and now fixed: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/fda3aa41a9250a072e8487882ae806ffe547f2bb