# Site never loads when using using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to play around with SignalR, but I seem to have hit a wall. When trying to load the site the browser seems to just sit there for a while waiting for a response. When I attach a debugger I see a the code below is executed, but `MapHubs` never returns (I let it run over lunch and it was still going when I came back)

```
public static class RegisterHubs
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();            
    }
}
```

My setup is a basic MVC4 Internet Application and then adding  the Microsoft.AspNet.Signalr Nuget Package (currently version 1.1.1-alpha2)

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in 1.0alpha2.  See: [SignalR seems to be slowing startup of my MVC / Azure application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612970/signalr-seems-to-be-slowing-startup-of-my-mvc-azure-application)

It was since fixed via https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/commit/fda3aa41a9250a072e8487882ae806ffe547f2bb

Comment: I'm not certain it is the same issue. The one referenced seems to indicate it will load eventually. Mine never does. I tried using another computer with the same code and it is working there. It is something on this PC.

Comment: Try downloading the SignalR source and referencing the appropriate projects and running your application that way.  See where the code gets stuck.