# SignalR Chat application not working with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr

This is the url from where I've downloaded the SignalR chat application between a web server and a web client.
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

This works fine when debugged on VS2013 but when published and deployed on IIS 7, somehow doesn't work as expected. To be more clear, I'm getting page displayed properly, but the dialog box doesn't popup for entering the username(which it is supposed to behave like) and the page remain static, when the url is hit from a browser.

Is this a configuration issue with SignalR and IIS ? Kindly help in making it work. I'm new to SignalR, and am trying to make a sample SignalR app work in IIS.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Got the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900536/signalr-applications-do-not-work-under-iis/16905370#16905370

Comment: by default in VS, we run the project at Kestral, run the project in VS itself but in release mode(allowing IIS in VS). there is no special configuration between signalR and IIS but in app.config we decide the path for Kestral and IIS separately, hopefully you will find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Applicatlion pool it should be ASP.Net4.0 (integrated).